# Problems with qorum device on Cluster Suite

Tags: rhel, cluster

I've built a 2 nodes ha-cluster with Cluster Suite on RH6.5; the configuration is very simple: 1 lvm shared volume, 1 fs over the shared volume and 1 vip. I've a failover domain and I'm using a scsi fence device (the configured device is the same device used by lvm).

I've also a quorum device configured:

```
mkqdisk v3.0.12.1

/dev/block/8:16:
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-3600140548972c3022b4412c9afceab98:
/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x600140548972c3022b4412c9afceab98:
/dev/disk/by-path/ip-10.254.252.232:3260-iscsi-iqn.2004-08.jp.buffalo.b0c7459f2696.clusuitequor-lun-0:
/dev/sdb:
    Magic:                eb7a62c2
    Label:                quorumdisk
    Created:              Wed Nov 11 14:46:37 2015
    Host:                 cl-su-01
    Kernel Sector Size:   512
    Recorded Sector Size: 512
```

but here starts the problem: on the first node cman starts fine, but on the second node qdiskd (and obviously cman) fails.

qdiskd.log on second node, tells me the following:

```
Nov 11 17:26:38 qdiskd Quorum Partition: /dev/block/8:16 Label: quorumdisk 
Nov 11 17:26:38 qdiskd Quorum Daemon Initializing 
Nov 11 17:26:38 qdiskd diskRawWriteShadow: Input/output error 
Nov 11 17:26:38 qdiskd diskRawWriteShadow: aligned write returned -1, not 512 Nov 11 17:26:38 qdiskd diskRawWriteShadow
Nov 11 17:26:38 qdiskd Error writing node ID block 4 
Nov 11 17:26:38 qdiskd Could not initialize status block! 
Nov 11 17:26:38 qdiskd Initialization failed
```

Shared and quorum devices are both iscsi luns.

Can anyone help me?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is advised to use a disk dedicated to quorum. I am assuming your are not in production environment as you are using fence_scsi.

Comment: The quorum disk is a dedicated iscsi device and yes, this is not a pro env. Im working on test env to do some test for a customer's specific request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

On the first node:

**/dev/sdb** is the quorum device

**/dev/sdc** is the shared volume (the fence device)

But on the second node the devices are inverted:

**/dev/sdc** is the quorum device

**/dev/sdb** is the shared volume (the fence device)

The first node has placed (rightly) a scsi reservation on its fence device, but for the second node this device name matched the quorum.

I remapped via udev the quorum device and I used this new named for cluster configuration.

Thanks to all.